Chev 2005 Silverado 2500 HD Starting Problem
My Chev 2005 Chev Silverado 2500 HD 4x4 is having starting problems.
Symptoms are. You turn the key it starts no problem after driving, You turn the key and it will just turn over and not start , turn the key again no starter turning over at all. Try again third or 5fth time it starts. Once the truck starts it will run no problem until you turn it off.
I have a new battery, I have changed the starter motor, Ignition key, starter relay, and crank position sensor. Problem still persists.
Where is the problem???????????????

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Might this video be of assistance to you? I'm assuming your engine is the 6.0L LQ9. If you have a diesel, this would not be your issue.
